# How can I preview the GRUB2 boot screen?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, images

I've been reading a [tutorial](http://dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html#mozTocId930378) that shows how to set the background image that will be displayed behind the GRUB2 boot options menu. However, I am concerned that the text might not be visible against the image I've chosen. How can I preview what the screen will look like, without having to restart the computer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `grub-emu`. On Debian based systems, this can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install grub-emu
```

Once you have installed it, you can run it to preview your `grub` setup:

```
sudo grub-emu
```

Comment: To get out of the emulator use c (command line) and then type 'reboot'

Comment: Note that you have to type in the original terminal, not the emulation window.